# Логика связей таблиц

Tags: sql, база-данных

Доброе времени суток.

Есть БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ТЗ:**

Классика - хранение и учет.

В БД должны храниться пользователи, раскиданные по ролям. У каждой роли есть свои атрибуты и свойства(дата начало работы, дети).

Пример: у Человека - Учителя Есть: Имя, Дата рождения, Предмет.
У Человека - Учителя, Родителя Есть: Имя, Дата рождения, Предмет, Дети.

**Условия БД(логика от обратного):**

1. "Ученик" не может быть "Учитель" и "Родитель"(в данном случае "Ученик не может быть "Взрослый")(мы рассматриваем школу. Если Ученик учиться в школе, то его дети там не учатся. Такое, по идее возможно...Но мало вероятно. Очень.)

**Что должно хранится.**

Пользователи, с определенным ролями и свойствами у этих ролей.

### ***Вопросы:***

### 1.

Уместно ли применение таблицы "Взрослый"? Как обычно решают подобные задачи?

**Зачем добавил?**

Удобнее писать логику.

**Вместо** "Человек не может быть одновременно быть ("Учитель" или "Родитель") и "Ученик""

**Пишем** "Человек не может быть одновременно быть "Взрослый" и "Ученик"".

### 2.

Есть условие "Человек не может быть одновременно "Взрослый" и "Ученик"".

**Пояснения:**

1. В базу нельзя занести человека(пользователя) как "Взрослый"(т.е нельзя сделать связь "Человек - Взрослый", когда уже есть связь "Ученик"( т.е когда есть связь "Человек - Ученик") и наоборот.
2. В select-запросе нужно отбирать тех кто является только взрослым или только учеником.

**Зачем?**

1. У каждой роли есть свои свойства(дата начала работы, дети и т.д), поэтому так разделенно
2. Элемент списка

Как поставить это условие в БД?

У меня такое чувство, что я подзабыл важные моменты и все дело в неправильной архитектуре.

**UPD**

И да, вариант с внешними ключами на таблицы "Учитель", "Родитель", "Ученик" мне известен. Но, насколько я знаю, это не хорошо.

Comment: Ну как минимум то, что на несколько `Human` могут ссылать на одну запись `User`. Потом можно сделать поле `Role` и в нем указывать `Ученик`, `Учитель`. Расскажите какая изначально стояла задача? Для чего таблица `Взрослый` ??

Comment: А почему учитель не может быть родителем ?

Comment: И что то мне подсказывает что одной таблицы "пользователи" более чем достаточно. Ну возможно вокруг нее будут какие нибудь роли, права доступа и т.п.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk такая задача и стоит. 1 хотел решить уникальым внешним ключом. Про "Взрослый" - написал в вопросе. Role я бы и сделал, но идея в том, что каждой роли соотвествует информация(начало работы, конец).

Comment: @Mike Может. Эмм, странно тогда будет выглядить взаимодействие с бд.

Comment: @Arantler чтовы делаете ? какую задачу решаете с помощью своей таблицы

Comment: @Arantler А что в нем будет странного ? Я говорю лишь то что вижу у вас на картинке, а на ней все избыточно.потому как судя по картинке БД ваша будет решать единственную задачу - вести информацию о пользователях системы, на большее в ней информации не видно. Структура БД должна отвечать тому, для чего она разрабатывается. Если бы я знал какую задачу вы собираетесь решать на самом деле я бы скорее всего пришел к какому то другому выводу нежели класть все в одну таблицу. Но решаемую задачу вы почему то не раскрываете - поэтому и правильного ответа на ваш вопрос быть не может.

Comment: @Mike Написал задачу в вопросе

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Добавил пояснения.

Comment: @Arantler Я не вижу задачи в вопросе. "учет информации" - это назначение любой БД. Даже из вашей фразы "_В базу нельзя было занести как взрослого того, кто уже занесён как ученик._" не ясно "Надо что бы было нельзя занести" или "Ранее было нельзя, а теперь можно". Какова же задача, зачем эту информацию вообще хранить. что должно там хранится и что _не должно_ туда ложится.

Comment: @Mike Так лучше?

Comment: @Arantler Что должно произойти, когда ученик закончил обучение и устроился на работу учителем ? Он должен будет завести себе новую запись в "пользователи" ? (для хранения истории старая запись наверняка должна будет остаться). Зачем разделены сущности "Пользователь" и "Человек" - такая модель позволяет завести хоть 5 разных HumanID для одного UserID. Вам надо что бы в системе через один логин могли работать разные люди ?

Comment: @Arantler По аналогии: зачем таблица "взрослый". У вас один человек может быть несколькими взрослыми. Итого от вашей модели остается "Пользователи" (они же человек), к нему напрямую "Ученик" (без собственного ID, уникальным ключем UserID, что бы он не мог несколько раз быть учеником [если не требуется обратное]). Так же напрямую таблица "Учитель" - тут свой ID видимо есть, потому как он может менять специализацию, увольняться и приходить опять. Таблицы "Родитель" видимо не существует, а напрямую к "пользователю" например таблица "Дети"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52686/discussion-between-arantler-and-mike).

Answer (score 0):

Я правильно понимаю, что когда вы говорите об облегчении логики, вы подразумеваете упрощение запросов?

Почему бы вам не использовать для всех объединённых понятий (на подобие Взрослые = Учители + Родители) такую вещь, как представления (view) ?

По второму вашему вопросу не совсем понятно.

Что вы имеете в виду? Вам нужно сделать так, чтобы в базу нельзя было занести как взрослого того, кто уже занесён как ученик? Или вам в select-запросе нужно отбирать тех кто является только взрослым или только учеником?

Comment: 1. Почти. Удобнее писать логику и при маштабировании она не будет особо меняться. Пишем "Человек не может быть одновременно быть "Взрослый" и "Ученик"". Пример: если добавиться поле "Директор", то логика не изменится.
2. А потому что один Взрослый может быть и "Учитель" и "Родитель" и "Директор"(в будущем).
3. Да и да. Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

### Варианты решения

### 1. Переписать архитектуру подобным образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это не совсем верно. Почему? Стоит перечитать все комментарии.

Если вкратце: не очень красиво, но решает проблему правда...Выяснилось, что все же может быть Ребенок(Ученик) Учителем или Родителем, хоть это и исключение. Поэтому...

### 2. Оставить все как есть(не проверять).

Но уведомлять пользователя в приложение, что это исключение.

**Цитата(из беседы, почитайте)** "
Даже если в начале в приложении жесткий запрет но структура БД позволяет - это не страшно и главное это как раз полезно для дальнейшего расширения задачи и ее понимания. Убрать запрет из приложения - не проблема. А архитектурный запрет при изменении потановки может заставить переделывать БД ..."

Comment: Вы все усложняете. С такой БД нереально работать. что бы добраться до какой то сути надо переклеить много "лишних" таблиц в итоге быстродействие системы будет никакое. В любом случае: если у вас две таблицы имеют одинаковый набор полей - то вы наверняка что то делаете не так. Сейчас ваша модель позволяет занести в БД пользователя UserID=1 и для него положить запись и в таблицу взрослых пользователей и в таблицу детей пользователей, после чего эта запись с UserID=1 по цепочке может быть внесена вообще во все таблицы на картинке.

Comment: И когда это произойдет в представление "Человек" один и тот же UserID=1 попадет дважды один раз слева и один раз справа. Зачем это надо ?

Comment: @Mike Согласен. Удивительно, почему эта проблема не пришла в голову. Это неимоверно очевидно.

Мне тоже это не нравится и кажется не логичным, но другого решения пока не приходит в голову. Я сейчас переписываю немного вопрос, опираясь на ваши комментарии.